# Post User Id within submitted form

Tags: php, mysql, post

First off I like to apologise if this question has already been answered. I will be upfront - I'm a novice user with PHP and I am doing my best to research before attempting to give you a headache.

Ok so here is my question:

I have listing page, using PHP. The user posts their advert etc. I am trying to add the function where once they have to log in and post some content, attach User I.D to posted content and link to their profile. I have a login script, created the database tables etc. I have also set up user tables etc.

To be more accurate, here is an example:

*User logs in and then enters info into a form:*

Post Title: blah blah

Post Contents: blah blah blah

**Post by user: ---> user-I.D-here- <---**

Like i said, i am sorry if this has been answered. I have tried to search the web but i'm either missing something or maybe i should give up lol.

Thank you for your time and patients.

Comment: Please, post your code when asking for help.

Comment: i believe he is asking directions, the way he asked question i guess he din't start coding yet :p

Comment: I think it's better to when user logged in save his id in session so as long as user is logged in in your site you have his id in session and can use it where you need, search google for practical example

Comment: Thanks mohsenkw, your advice has helped me alot.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us the code you have worked on. I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)